# how to connect zabbix api from within the containers?

Tags: java, docker, zabbix

we are running 3 components of zabbix. Zabbix-webui, zabbix server and mysql database as docker containers using docker-compose file.
have created another springboot application which is dockerized & trying to connect to zabbix api. All 4 images are running within the same compose file.

How can we connect to zabbix api and fetch the api results in our application?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume this `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  zabbix-frontend:
    restart: always
    image: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql
    environment:
     - DB_SERVER_HOST=someserver
  [...]

  some-application:
    restart: always
    image: yourapplication:latest
```

Your `some-application` container should connect to `http://zabbix-frontend` to consume the APIs.

To test http reachability from within the application container (`a5d95c2cc9a2` in the example):

```
# docker exec -it a5d95c2cc9a2 sh

sh-4.2# curl -i -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' \
   -d '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"user.login", \
   "params":{ "user":"youruser","password":"somepassword"},"auth":null,"id":0}' \
   http://zabbix-frontend/api_jsonrpc.php

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 21 Jan 2019 19:17:55 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=20
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.17
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000

{"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","id":0}
```